# Bash script execute command on multiple servers

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm trying to login into multiple servers and execute the following command:

```
arp -an|grep lanx>lanx
```

I'm  using this method:

```
ssh admin@10.x.x.x arp\ -an|grep\ lanx >lanx
```

but it is not working its giving me an error

Comment: Please show us the exact error you are getting. It might be though, because you didn't put the "arp" command in quotes und thus the pipe is interpreted locally and not the remote machine. Try `ssh admin@10.x.x.x 'arp -an|grep lanx' > lanx`.

Comment: Yeah this have done the trick, it was cuase the ' ' thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1):

ideally just put the commands in quotes like this:

```
ssh admin@10.x.x.x '/sbin/arp -an | grep lanx' > lanx
```

or

```
ssh admin@10.x.x.x '/sbin/arp -an' | grep lanx > lanx
```

The other problem might be the user admin on your machine does not have arp in PATH (is he root? arp is usually in /sbin/ and /sbin/ is usually not in PATH of a regular user.

Answer (score 0):

put in subshell.  something like this will make things more clear:

```
(ssh xxxx arp -an) | grep lanx > /tmp/lanx
```